# Jquery how to check if a input has a number higher then 99

Tags: jquery

Was wanting to know how to check using jquery if a input contains a number higher then 99

Answer (score 24, accepted):

try this:

```
if(parseInt($("selector").val()) > 99) {
    /*if it is*/
}
```

or if you are checking it on change:

```
$("selector").change(function(){
     if(parseInt(this.value) > 99){
        /*if it is*/
     } 
})
```

**Edit** as said in the below comments, it might be better to use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt` to compare the numbers

Comment: @Lawrence i added on if you are checking it on input change

Comment: @Lawrence, im guessing thats not for abt 5 mins due to stack restrictions ^_^

Comment: Yes that is true it wont let me say its answered for a couple more minutes

Comment: @Lawrence and now that time restriction should be up ^_^

Comment: you don't need parsefloat or parseint: ('99' == 99) = true. also: ("100" > 99) = true

Comment: @herostwist, even though you might not have to in this instance its a good habit to get into so you don't forget for those times when you really do need to do it

Comment: This code will fail on an input value that contains its value as 99.10. Technically this is greater than 99 but this code will cast it to 99 and the > check will fail. Only a problem if you are dealing with fractions.

Comment: @Nikhil, so use `parseFloat` instead

Comment: Yup parseFloat would work but again (and sorry for being so picky!) the code does not handle conditions where inputs might not be numbers. Ideally input validation should be performed in slightly greater detail :)

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($("#myfield").val() > 99) {

}
```

Comment: its nothing to do with jQuery. in JavaScript ('100' == 100) = true

Answer (score 1):

```
if(parseInt($(YOURINPUT).val()) > 99) // do something
```

Comment: you don't need parsefloat or parseint: ('99' == 99) = true. also: ("100" > 99) = true

Comment: @herostwist: I already got into situation, where the conversion didn't work correctly without parseInt, so I like doing it safe since then. I don't remember the context, so don't ask :)

Answer (score 1):

If by input you mean text, then use the following:

```
if (parseFloat($("#inputid").val()) > 99) {
   //do something
}
```

Comment: you don't need parsefloat or parseint: ('99' == 99) = true. also: ("100" > 99) = true

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this:

```
if ($("input.INPUTNAME").val() > 99) {
//above 99 code
}
```

You may want to have an else command, if the input is below 99.

```
if ($("input.INPUTNAME").val() > 99) {
    //above 99 code.
    }
else{
     //Not above 99 code.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do it

```
var value = $("input selector").eq(0).val();
if(isNaN(value)){
 //do stuff
}

else{
var num = value - 0;
if(num>99)
{
 //value is greater than 99
}

}
```

Comment: what is the `num = value - 0;` for?

Comment: This is to convert a string representation of a number into a true number. this will convert "99" string literal to 99 number. There are various ways of doing this (parseInt, parseFloat etc.). This is one way that I use.

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

html:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" />
```

jquery:

```
var nMyInput = $("#myInput").val();
if (typeof nMyInput != "undefined"){
    if(!isNaN(nMyInput)){
        if (parseInt(nMyInput) > 99) {
            /* do your stuff */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wow you dont really need all those if statements beforehand. `parseInt` should do all that for you

Comment: I didn't knew the parseInt did all the job (detect if are undefined and if the text are not number) ^_^'

Answer (score -1):

I guess typically with jQuery you would have to have the name of the form

```
<form id="myForm" action="comment.php" method="post"> 
    number: <input id="form_number" type="text" name="number" /> 
    Comment: <textarea name="comment"></textarea> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" /> 
</form>
```

you would select the form and its input.

```
var myInt = parseInt(jQuery("#form-number-url").attr("value"));
```

then you can compare it with any other integer.