# Validation of input field after value is inserted without button click Laravel HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a user with certain number assigned to them let's say 100. I have the value 100 passed to my view. There is an input field such that user can enter any value but if the value user enter is greater than 100 a warning must be displayed. I want this warning to be displayed as soon as user is finished entering the value and move to next input field. I want the warning to be shown without any button click.

Comment: Do you have any code yet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery how to check if a input has a number higher then 99](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704957/jquery-how-to-check-if-a-input-has-a-number-higher-then-99)

Comment: @Damian i'hv added an example see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643242/validation-of-input-field-after-value-is-inserted-without-button-click-laravel-h/37643432#37643432

Answer (score 0):

Just add an oninput event to your input field and validate it with JavaScript.

```
<input type="text" value="100" oninput="validate()">

<script>
function validate() {
   // validate
}
</script>
```

Or do it like here [setting oninput event with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355499/setting-oninput-event-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `<input type="text" id="number" />` is input field.

```
$('#number').on('change', function(){
    if(isNaN(parseInt($(this).val())) || $(this).val() > 100){
      alert('You are doing wrong.');
      $(this).focus().val(100);
    }
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#number').on('change', function(){
    if(isNaN(parseInt($(this).val())) || $(this).val() > 100){
      alert('You are doing wrong.');
      $(this).focus().val(100);
    }
  })
})
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <label>Number: <input type="text" id="number" /></label><br>
            <label>Another Input<input type="text" id="number" /></label>
```