# How to restrict input field value to certain number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have an HTML table inside which i have a column `AcceptedQty` which is input field

Total i have 5 columns `Code`,`Item Name`,`unitcode`,`Quantity` and `AcceptedQty` two of them `Quantity` and `AcceptedQty` have same values but `AcceptedQty` is input field so user can input any number inside that and i have made that type="number" to enter only numbers

**What i am trying to do**

- when user input any number inside the input field it should not allow him to enter greater number to the corresponding quantity
- suppose for `code` 1326 `Quantity` is 3 so while editing `AcceptedQty` i want to restrict user not to enter any number greater then 3
- here i have a HTML table and so many rows that's why finding it dificult to do

**Snippet**

```js
var tableDataDraft = [{
    "Code": "1326",
    "Item Name": "PINEAPPLE KG",
    "unitcode": "NOS",
    "Quantity": "3.0000",
    "AcceptedQty": "3.0000"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1494",
    "Item Name": "2D CAKE CHARGES PER KG",
    "unitcode": "NOS",
    "Quantity": "3.0000",
    "AcceptedQty": "3.0000"
  }
]

function addTableDraft(tableDataDraft) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableDataDraft[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
    tr.classList.add("text-center");
    tr.classList.add("head")
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableDataDraft.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input"); //creating input field hidden
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var tabledata = tableDataDraft[i][col[j]];
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Code'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) { //now setting html attributes
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Code');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Item Name'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Name');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['unitcode'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Unit_code');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (col[j] === 'Quantity') {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Quantity');
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (col[j] === 'AcceptedQty') {
        var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
        quantityField.style.border = "none";
        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "right";
        quantityField.setAttribute("name", "AcceptedQty");
        quantityField.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");
        quantityField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
        quantityField.setAttribute("type", "number");
        quantityField.setAttribute("required", "required");
        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
        quantityField.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
      }

      if (j > 1)
        tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
    }
  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("table");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
addTableDraft(tableDataDraft)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="table-responsive" id="commonDvScroll">
  <table id=table></table>
</div>
```

Comment: *"and i have made that type="tel" to enter only numbers"* ?! `type="number"`. "tel" is a *telephone number*.

Comment: @dheerajkumar You can use javascript onchange function and can restrict the number in AcceptedQty

Comment: @CaptainPlanet that is the question how? i am really finding hard to do that

Comment: @dheerajkumar this  might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704957/jquery-how-to-check-if-a-input-has-a-number-higher-then-99

Comment: @CaptainPlanet yup it is helpfull

Comment: @CaptainPlanet but there is one issue, when user enter greater number then i am showing alert so when user destroy alert i am focusing `this.focus` to the field which has greater input but it is focusing on the next input field

Comment: just add the field name `.focus` @dheerajkumar

Comment: @CaptainPlanet i tried that but it is going to the next element,please check once

Comment: @dheerajkumar Please add the code snippet, so that I can check

Comment: @CaptainPlanet it is working fine in crome but in mozilla it is focusing on next field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @T.J Crowder mentioned, make use of the input type `number`

That input type allows you to set a `max` value, which is based of the previous columns value

Additionally, you'll want to add an event listener to the input to "listen" / detect changes to the input, so that you can act upon any changes, restricting the input value as you see fit

---

```js
var tableDataDraft = [{
    "Code": "1326",
    "Item Name": "PINEAPPLE KG",
    "unitcode": "NOS",
    "Quantity": "3.0000",
    "AcceptedQty": "3.0000"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1494",
    "Item Name": "2D CAKE CHARGES PER KG",
    "unitcode": "NOS",
    "Quantity": "3.0000",
    "AcceptedQty": "3.0000"
  }
]

function addTableDraft(tableDataDraft) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableDataDraft[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
    tr.classList.add("text-center");
    tr.classList.add("head")
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableDataDraft.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input"); //creating input field hidden
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var tabledata = tableDataDraft[i][col[j]];
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Code'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) { //now setting html attributes
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Code');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Item Name'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Name');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['unitcode'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Unit_code');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (col[j] === 'Quantity') {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Quantity');
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (col[j] === 'AcceptedQty') {
        var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
        quantityField.style.border = "none";
        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "right";
        quantityField.setAttribute("name", "AcceptedQty");
        quantityField.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");
        quantityField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
        quantityField.setAttribute("type", "number");
        quantityField.setAttribute("required", "required");
        quantityField.setAttribute("max", parseInt(tableDataDraft[i]["Quantity"]));
        quantityField.setAttribute("min", 0);
        quantityField.setAttribute("step", 0.1);


        quantityField.addEventListener("change", function() {
          let max = parseFloat(this.getAttribute('max'));
          let min = parseFloat(this.getAttribute('min'));
          let val = parseFloat(this.value)
          val = val > max ? max : val;
          val = val < min ? min : val;
          if (val != this.value) {
            alert("Input is incorrect");
            this.focus();
          }
          this.value = val;

        });
        quantityField.setAttribute("min", 0);

        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
        quantityField.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
      }

      if (j > 1)
        tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
    }
  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("table");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
addTableDraft(tableDataDraft)
```

```css
input:invalid {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="table-responsive" id="commonDvScroll">
  <table id=table></table>
</div>
```

Comment: hey i can enter number greater then 3  please check your snippet

Comment: again it is taking greater then 3

Comment: hey i am replacing   `this.value = val;` to alert("somealert") but issue is it is not focusing on the input field which has greater value

Comment: updated using alert and some css styling for indication

Comment: hey it is not taking 2.5 why? sir you there?

Comment: it's cause i was using `parseInt` instead of `parseFloat`... i and due to the nature of the input type `number`, i have updated the snippet.

just as a heads up dheeraj, any additional questions that are not in your original question should be in a new question :)

Comment: hey sir i have posted a new question can you please help or guide me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55846400/appended-new-row-is-not-behaving-like-previous-one-row

Answer (score 1):

> and i have made that type="tel" to enter only numbers

Use `type="number"` (`"tel"` is a *telephone number*) and the `min` and `max` attributes (and reflected properties) of the [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) (and `step` if you don't want fractional values). Probably also include an `input` handler to handle browsers without HTML5 field features.

See the `***` commented lines:

```js
var tableDataDraft = [{
    "Code": "1326",
    "Item Name": "PINEAPPLE KG",
    "unitcode": "NOS",
    "Quantity": "3.0000",
    "AcceptedQty": "3.0000"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1494",
    "Item Name": "2D CAKE CHARGES PER KG",
    "unitcode": "NOS",
    "Quantity": "3.0000",
    "AcceptedQty": "3.0000"
  }
]

function addTableDraft(tableDataDraft) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableDataDraft[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
    tr.classList.add("text-center");
    tr.classList.add("head")
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableDataDraft.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input"); //creating input field hidden
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var tablerow = tableDataDraft[i]; // ***
      var tabledata = tablerow[col[j]]; // ***
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Code'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) { //now setting html attributes
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Code');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Item Name'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Name');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['unitcode'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Unit_code');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (col[j] === 'Quantity') {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Quantity');
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (col[j] === 'AcceptedQty') {
        var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
        quantityField.style.border = "none";
        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "right";
        quantityField.setAttribute("name", "AcceptedQty");
        quantityField.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");
        quantityField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
        quantityField.setAttribute("type", "number");
        quantityField.min = 0;                 // ***
        quantityField.max = tablerow.Quantity; // ***
        quantityField.setAttribute("required", "required");
        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
        quantityField.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
      }

      if (j > 1)
        tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
    }
  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("table");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
addTableDraft(tableDataDraft)
```

```css
input:invalid {
  color: #d00;
  border: 1px solid #d00 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="table-responsive" id="commonDvScroll">
  <table id=table></table>
</div>
```

Note that the user will still be able to *enter* a higher number, but the form won't validate. See [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation) on MDN.

Comment: i have tried this kind of thing look via keyboard i can enter greater then 3

Comment: @dheerajkumar - That's right, but the form won't be valid. I've added a link to an MDN tutorial on HTML5 form validation. (In general, preventing the user typing is error-prone and not great UX; instead, tell them what they've entered is incorrect so they can fix it.)

Comment: but i am not using form.submit to submit form i am just using .click to make ajax call so in that case form validation will not work

Comment: @dheerajkumar - Read the article. :-) You can use validation features without submitting the form.

Comment: @dheerajkumar - For instance, I've updated the snippet above to use the `:invalid` pseudo-class to flag the field when it's invalid.

Comment: In terms of user experience, this a way better approach