# Can I run a function if 35 or greater is entered into textera for free shipping

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Instead of using checkbox to call this function is it possible for me to run it if a number 35 is enter into a textera. So if free shipping is 35+ it will run the function below

this is the code for the number input for free shipping is

```
<input type="number" id="wcfmmp_byc_free_shipping_amount" name="wcfmmp_shipping_by_country[_free_shipping_amount]" class="wcfm-text wcfm_non_negative_input wcfm_ele" value="75" placeholder="No Free Shipping">
```

```
// -----------------------------------------
// 1. Add new checkbox to product edit page (General tab)
  
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'bbloomer_add_badge_checkbox_to_products' );        
  
function bbloomer_add_badge_checkbox_to_products() {           
woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array( 
'id' => 'custom_badge', 
'class' => '', 
'label' => 'Show Custom Badge'
) 
);      
}
  
// -----------------------------------------
// 2. Save checkbox via custom field
  
add_action( 'save_post', 'bbloomer_save_badge_checkbox_to_post_meta' );
  
function bbloomer_save_badge_checkbox_to_post_meta( $product_id ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;
    if ( isset( $_POST['custom_badge'] ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $product_id, 'custom_badge', $_POST['custom_badge'] );
    } else delete_post_meta( $product_id, 'custom_badge' );
}

// -----------------------------------------
// 3. Display badge @ single product page if checkbox checked
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'bbloomer_display_badge_if_checkbox', 6 );
  
function bbloomer_display_badge_if_checkbox() {
    global $product;     
    if ( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'custom_badge', true ) ) {
        echo '
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704957/jquery-how-to-check-if-a-input-has-a-number-higher-then-99

Comment: What is the name of the function you want to call?

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS function bbloomer_display_badge_if_checkbox() {
    global $product;     
    if ( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'custom_badge', true ) ) {
        echo '

Comment: instead of using number 1 and 2 checkbox to echo the div in number 3 on product page I just need if 35 is entered in to the input it will automatically apply the div

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the [onchange event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) when they change the value in the textbox.

Comment: wcfmmp_byc_free_shipping_amount is the ID for the onchange event

Answer (score 0):

This should at least start you in the right place.

Being WP you may have to change the `$`  to a "safer" alternative.

Note, this is a sample and may not work out of the box. Hopefully, it's enough to point you in the right direction.

At the risk of stating the obvious, this will need to be enqueued onto the relevant page.

```
$('#wcfmmp_byc_free_shipping_amount').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val()>=35){
        //do the thing
    } else {
        //don't do the thing
    }
});
```

Comment: not dynamically. you should _always_ validate inputs serverside to ensure it's correct though.

Comment: function bbloomer_save_badge_checkbox_to_post_meta( $product_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['custom_badge'] ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $product_id, 'custom_badge', $_POST['custom_badge'] );
    } else delete_post_meta( $product_id, 'custom_badge' );
}

Comment: cant i change this code to reflect what I'm trying to do

Comment: you can definitely, and _should_  confirm in the PHP end. But if you want it to change _dynamically_ on the front end (what the user see's) based off what the user does that will need to be done with jQuery as above.